# Use php to trim URL to just domain name by removing protocol and path

Tags: php, regex

Given "http://google.com/path-to-page" trip to "google.com"

What php and regex would be appropriate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and get the `host` part.

Comment: $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

Comment: Or, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will get you www.domain.com or domain.com.