# Get Domain Name with suffix (Only Domain) (Regex PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Get Domain Name with suffix (Only Domain)

I need regex in PHP or JavaScript to resolve domains.

**any suffix (com,org,net,us,ar,....) And any Protocol (http,https,ftp,...)**

Example:

```
array(
  , 'http://domainname.com'
  , 'http://domainname.com/whatever/you/get/the/idea'
  , 'http://www.domainname.com/whatever/you/get/the/idea'
  , 'http://www.domainname.com'
  , 'https://s1.s2.domainname.com/321.com/www.654.vom/'
  , 'https://s1.domainname.com'
  , 'https://s1.domainname.com/domain1.com/'
  , 'https://domain1.com.domainname.com'
  , 's1.s2.domainname.com/321.com/www.654.vom/'
  , 's1.domainname.com'
  , 's1.domainname.com/domain1.com/'
  , 'domain1.com.domainname.com'
);
```

Result:
for all Result is **domainname.com**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to find domain name without www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427603/regex-to-find-domain-name-without-www)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use php to trim URL to just domain name by removing protocol and path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122292/use-php-to-trim-url-to-just-domain-name-by-removing-protocol-and-path)

Answer (score 1):

JS, using the modern [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
   u = 'https://s1.s2.domainname.com/321.com/www.654.vom/'
   host = new URL(u).host.split('.').slice(-2).join('.')
```

An old-style regex way

```
   host = u.match(/^\w+:\/\/.*?(\w+\.\w+)(\/|$)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A way without regex:

```
$urls = array('http://domainname.com',
              'http://domainname.com/whatever/you/get/the/idea',
              'http://www.domainname.com/whatever/you/get/the/idea',
              'http://www.domainname.com',
              'https://s1.s2.domainname.com/321.com/www.654.vom/',
              'https://s1.domainname.com',
              'https://s1.domainname.com/domain1.com/',
              'https://domain1.com.domainname.com');

$domains = array_map(function ($url) {
    $chunks = explode('.', parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST));
    $first_level_dn = array_pop($chunks);
    return array_pop($chunks) . '.' . $first_level_dn;
}, $urls);

print_r($domains);
```

Comment: thankyou. i test your code. its works but i need regex for get domain name.